# Choosing Web Automation Stack

Tags: selenium, testing, browser-automation

I found it over a few references that it is recommended to go with the same stack for creating automation suite that is being used for the development of the application, i.e., using Java for writing tests if application is Java based.

Is there any specific reason for the same? Or is there any specific hindrance if not followed.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally say that developers making an application in one language will probably feel more familiar writing the tests in the same language. And Integration tests should preferably be written by the developer who wrote the feature.

So using the same language for your test suite and your application development increases the odds your developers will be able to write and fix tests for features they create and fix themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I think that should be team decision, the same as what testing frameworks to use. But it's totally fine to use for example [Spock](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/index.html) which is groovy based framework if your application is java based.